# AngularJS - Filter already selected items from ng-select inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I've found similar questions but no one is having the same problem I'm having. I have a list of localizations that a user can add to (for building their own localization of our UI). They can have multiple languages for the same item, so they can type the text and select the corresponding language from a dropdown.

I only want them to be able to select a language once (it makes no sense for them to have two of the same language in the list). Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="divider-header">
  <h4>{{'contactAttributes.localization.title' | translate}}</h4>
  <button id="add-label-btn" class="btn pull-right" title="Add a label"
    ng-click="addLocalization()">
  <i class="fa fa-plus center"></i>
  </button>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="item in localizations track by $index">
  <div class="input-group localization-group">
    <label>{{'value.label' | translate}}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.label">
    <label>{{'value.language' | translate}}</label>
    <select
      required
      ng-options="locale.value as locale.label for locale in localeNames | filter: alreadySelected" 
      ng-model="item.language"></select>
    <i id="remove-localization-label"
      class="fa fa-times remove"
      ng-click="removeLocalization($index)"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

The "alreadySelected" filter looks like this (in a directive hence scope instead of $scope):

```
scope.alreadySelected = function(language) {
  return !scope.localizations.filter(function(selectedValue) {
    return selectedValue.language === language.value;
  }).length;
};
```

scope.localizations contains the already selected items. This almost works, but it has the effect of filtering out the option selected from the select box itself, so that when you select an option, it gets filtered out and the select box shows up as blank. I need the selected item of that select box to still show up and be selectable, but only in that particular select box (not the others in the ng-repeat).

Let me know if this could use clarification. Thanks!

EDIT: Here's a plunkr showing the issue - https://plnkr.co/edit/ALu00gitPg7GLfdGQ75a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution with a bit of help from lodash. Change ng-options to this:

```
ng-options="locale.value as locale.label for locale in availableLocales($index)"
```

Replace the alreadySelected function with this:

```
scope.availableLocales = function(localizationIndex) {
        return scope.localeNames.filter(function(locale) {
          return !_.find(scope.localizations, function(localization, idx) {
            if (localizationIndex === idx) return false;
            return localization.language === locale.value;
          });
        });
      };
```

If anyone has an alternative solution feel free to share, otherwise, thanks for being my rubber duck, StackOverflow. :P